# Duvida banco de dados / sistema de controle de lotes

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou elaborando um projeto no qual me deparei com um problema em que não sei qual seria a forma mais eficiente de se fazer.

Meu projeto conta com um cadastro de produtos no qual quero controlar por lote, exemplo:

Produto - Borracha

Lote 1 - Comprei um lote de 100 borrachas por R$ 50 reais e vou vender a R$ 1 real cada uma totalizando R$ 100 reais.

Lote 2 - Comprei um lote de 100 borrachas por R$ 70 reais e vou vender a R$ 1,70. aumento devido a o período de compra

Meu banco conta com 2 tabelas até agora, Produto e Produto_lote no qual vou deixar abaixo como está. Minha duvida é: como dar baixa na quantidade de cada lote quando houver uma venda e automaticamente o sistema passar para o próximo lote sem que haja alteração no campo quantidade para que futuramente sirva como um histórico.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma tabela para controle de histórico... Assim a sua tabela de estoque terá a quantidade atual, e na sua tabela de histórico voce terá registrado todas as operaçoes de compra/venda de produtos... exemplo:

```
ID   ID_PRODUTO   OPERACAO   QUANTIDADE   DATA
1        1          COMPRA       1        19/10/2015
2        1          VENDA        1        19/10/2015
```

e voce cria uma trigger na tabela de estoque para capturar operações e fazer o registro no histórico

Comment: Sim mas o certo então seria: ao realizar uma venda eu remove 1 na quantidade da tabela estoque e ao chegar a 0, realizar uma consulta de todos os lotes para saber qual é o o próximo? se for isso, após 5 anos de empresa terá muito lotes fazendo o sistema lento para consultar todos os lotes e verificar o primeiro cadastro e ainda contem quantidade.

Comment: Olha.. eu penso que controle de estoque deve ter a quantidade atual de produtos... e opcionalmente, a quantidade inicial... nao penso que procurar o proximo lote seja um problema de desempenho, mas se for.. crie uma FK para o proximo lote.. assim, quando precisar pegar o proximo lote, nao precisara fazer a pesquisa..

Comment: Eu deveria criar um campo 'Lote Atual' na tabela Produto então? e ai em cada lote eu amarro com o próximo lote?

Comment: é uma alternativa